# Set one CSS property to the value of another in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

For example, to animate a box from the left, I can set "left" to the negative value of "width", and animate it to zero:

```
 $('.box').each(function(){
      $(this)
           .css('left', $(this).width()*-1 )
           .animate({'left':0},1000)
           ;
 });
```

Is there a way to do this without the each function? THIS JQUERY IS TOO VERBOSE!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you needed to add the "each" in the first place, because most jQuery functions work on multiple elements simultaneously.  This should work:

```
 $('.box').css('left', $(this).width()*-1 ).animate({'left':0},1000);
```

EDIT: code doesn't work as mentioned in the comments, because $(this) doesn't refer to the right object.  This should fix it:

```
 var $box = $box.css('left', $box.width()*-1 ).animate({'left':0},1000);
```

Comment: Doesn't the "this" in your example live in the scope that contains the whole statement, not in the scope of $('.box')?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `function` in its own function called `animateBox()`. Then you can do this:

```
$('.box').each(animateBox);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's not really what I'm asking.  I was just trying to see if there's some jQuery magic that I'm not aware of.